# Windows shutdown dialog

Tags: windows, winapi, shutdown

Is there a way to bring up the Windows XP shutdown dialog (the one with the three buttons – Suspend, Shutdown, Restart and Hibernate when Shift is pressed) using any language (preferred: C/C++, VB, Haskell, batches)?

I think I can load the msgina.dll in my C++ program, but I dunno what to do next – what function in the dll is used to show the dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your language has a way to do basic file I/O and invoke shortcuts on Windows, try this tip from [here](http://www.onecomputerguy.com/windowsxp_tips.htm#shutdown_dialog):

> - Create a new txt file somewhere on your system, open it and put in this one line:
>     `(new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")).ShutdownWindows();`
> - Save and close the file. Change the extension to `*.js`.
> - You can make a shortcut to that file to make it easy to shut down your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'm just curious about other ways to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

I find PowerShell to be more elegant than other Windows scripting options.

```
(New-Object -Com Shell.Application).ShutdownWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out (14 years later) that a simple solution is to send a WM_CLOSE message to the "progman" window, this will trigger the standard shutdown dialog (tested in Win 10 and Win 11):

```
SendMessageW(FindWindowW(L"progman", NULL), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```